# Find the real and imaginary part of $\sqrt{(R+i\omega L) (R C/L+i\omega C)}$

Tags: complex-numbers

I want to seperate the real and imaginary part of the following, but I'm stuck.
$$
\gamma=\alpha+i\beta=\sqrt{(R+i\omega L)\Big (\frac{R C}{L}+i\omega C\Big)}
$$
Attempt:
\begin{align}
\sqrt{(R+i\omega L)\Big (\frac{R C}{L}+i\omega  C\Big)}
&=\sqrt{\frac{R^2C}{L}+i\omega CR+i\omega RC+i^2 \omega^2LC}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{R^2C}{L}+i\omega 2RC-\omega^2LC}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{R^2C}{L}-\omega^2LC+i\omega 2 RC}
\end{align}
And I'm stuck here...

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $$\frac {RC}L + i \omega C = \frac CL (R+i\omega L) $$

Answer (score 0):

You can restart from you last step

$$
\alpha+i\beta =\sqrt{\frac{R^2C}{L}-\omega^2LC+i\omega 2 RC}
=\sqrt{{C\over L}\left(R^2-\omega^2L^2+i\omega 2 RL\right)}
$$
Square, then equal real parts and imaginary parts

$$\begin{align}
&\alpha ^2 - \beta ^2 &=& \quad{C\over L}\left(R^2-\omega^2L^2\right) \tag 1\\
&2\alpha\beta &=& \quad 2\omega RC\tag 2\\
\end{align}
$$
From $(2)$ we get $\beta=\omega RC/\alpha.$ Upload it into $(1)$ and solve the biquadratic equation 
$$\alpha ^4 - {C\over L}\left(R^2-\omega^2L^2\right)\alpha^2-\omega^2R^2C^2=0.$$
$\alpha, \beta$ are reals but I am not sure if they can be negative (in electronics or in other science), so I prefer to write both mathematically valid solutions:
$$\alpha + i\beta =\pm \left(R\sqrt{C\over L}+i\omega\sqrt{CL}\right)$$